# How to block anything but internet(firefox) from UFW?

Tags: firewall

1. I want to use this flash drive only for secure access, to use my banking account and this kinds of stuffs. Which rules should I use?
2. I'm very newbie on ubuntu, and I need your help. This flash drive only will be for this. (safe for my mind when i access my web mail, bank account, paypal,etc).
3. And I'll try to understand more so I can use the Ubuntu for other things, such as mailing, gaming, spotify, facebook and etc. Can you guys recommend me something, so I can learn, which rules to apply ?
   Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I presume from your question that you have installed Ubuntu on a flash drive and wish to run it as a live session each time.

To enable the firewall in a terminal you should run:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo service ufw restart
```

As you are using a live USB, you will need to type these commands every time you use Ubuntu in that way.

This will give you the default firewall settings provided by ufw, which blocks almost all incoming traffic, but allows all outgoing traffic. In simple language, this means that you are free to make any connection from your computer, but others will not be able to make a connection to your computer. Of course it will not protect you from your own actions, e.g. if you decide to use a banking website with poor security.

For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall